# ARIMA_DEPRECATION_ERROR

Tags: arima

```
statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA and statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA have
been removed in favor of statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA (note the .
between arima and model) and statsmodels.tsa.SARIMAX.

statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA makes use of the statespace framework and
is both well tested and maintained. It also offers alternative specialized
parameter estimators.
```

file_path = 'market-price.csv'
bitcoin_df = pd.read_csv(file_path, names = ['day', 'price'])
bitcoin_df

bitcoin_df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(bitcoin_df['day'])
bitcoin_df

bitcoin_df.index = bitcoin_df['day']
bitcoin_df.set_index('day', inplace=True)

from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import statsmodels.api as sm

model = ARIMA(data, order=(2,1,2))